# If you disturb a Jenga block, can you push it back into place?

Tags: jenga

In Jenga, when you are moving your block out and another block next to it moves, are you allowed to push the other block(s) back?

Comment: I don't know.. can you?

Answer (score 11):

According to the [official 2000 version](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Jenga_2000.PDF) of the rules:

> As play proceeds and the weight of the tower shifts, some blocks become looser than others and are easier to remove. You can touch other blocks to find a loose one — but if you move a block out of place, you must fix it (using one hand only) before touching another block.

Since this rule includes the proviso *before touching another block* I take this to mean that you can't touch blocks after you have started to remove your block.

I believe it would be within the spirit of the rules that you could try and replace the block you started to remove, then try and remove the block you disturbed.

The key is that you can only touch one block at a time with only one hand.

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting the rules correctly.  All that is saying to me is "you can only use one hand" and "you can't end your turn with a block half sticking out.  You must fix it"

Comment: You must fix it *before touching another block*. It's pretty clear you can only manipulate one block at a time. What did I get wrong?

Comment: "The key is that you can only touch one block at a time with only one hand."  I think it is fine to touch other blocks as long as you do not move them.

Comment: @Andrey I too thought that you can touch multiple blocks with the remaining fingers of one hand as long as you don't move them.. So, which is the right was to play?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one hand. you can touch multiple blocks at a time to support the tower to get a block out as long as it's only one hand as well. If you disturb a block while trying to get your block out, you may leave it there but it is recommended to fix it so the tower doesn't fall or leave the next player with a move.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation where a block touching the block you are removing is so loose that it gets significantly moved while you remove your piece there isn't much point in caring about the second piece. All that really happens is you give the next player a very easy turn because they know a piece that will come out easily.

From a game play point of view there really isn't any difference in all the possible rules:

- Use the removed piece to tap back into place any dislodged pieces.
- Use other parts of the same hand to hold the loose piece in place.
- If a second block is disturbed you must replace the piece you are attempting to take and take a different piece (probably one you found to be moving during the other attempt).
- Remove the piece in the other direction so it doesn't disturb a second piece (wont always work, sometimes a piece will be disturbed which ever way you attempt to take out the piece).
- Just leave the other pieces where they lie.

While it might be important to pick a rule, I can't see a huge strategic difference between them.